# How do I ensure Visual C++ doesn't allow scoped enum access?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums

I have a C++ codebase which is compiled using various versions of GCC and Visual Studio (2017).  Some of our programmers (with C# backgrounds) tend to fully qualify the name of an enum (e.g. `ClassName::EnumName::EnumValue` vs. the proper `ClassName::EnumValue`).  Visual Studio seems to be fine with this usage (even though the enum is not defined as `enum class`, per C++11), but GCC (correctly) errors out.

What can I do to make Visual Studio give errors similar to GCC, in this case?

Edit: I should note that the GCC version we require tends to be pretty old (before 6.1)

Comment: `ClassName::EnumName::EnumValue` and `ClassName::EnumValue` should both be legal in C++11 and above.  Could we get an example?

Comment: GCC doesn't produce an error in the scenario you described. At least not when I [tried it](https://godbolt.org/z/ytY7DY).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux It's an error through GCC 5.5.

Comment: @TreDubZedd Did you turn on C++11? (`-std=c++11`): https://godbolt.org/z/iMfQrH

Comment: @NathanOliver We are unable to use C++11, at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to be able to make MSVS cause a compiler error.  With the introduction of scoped enums it became legal to to refer to a non scoped enumeration using the enum name.  That means `ClassName::EnumName::EnumValue` and `ClassName::EnumValue` are both legal in C++11 and above.

MSVC 2017 only supports `/std:[c++14|c++17|c++latest]` for it's C++ standard to compile against so it will always be legal to `ClassName::EnumName::EnumValue`.

This will probably lead to more issues if you are not going to compile against C++14 with your other compilers as the MSVS people might use other C++14 and above features that wont compile in C++98/03/11.